# Angular - Reactive form valueChanges. Avoid nested subscriptions

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming, angular-reactive-forms

### The issue

So. I'm trying to **pre-populate** a reactive form with **async data** that will be changing a lot. The asyncData$ is fed from the **AppComponent** to an **@input()** in a child component - **FormComponent** -  which handles the form.

**Subscribing** inside the **tap()** operator of the **dataForm$** was the **ONLY** way i could make **valueChanges** work and actually emit values, BUT nested subscriptions is a no no, so i would like to find a better/cleaner solution which avoids that - preferably by using observables. It may jsut be that I am missing something obvious

Does anybody have a suggestion?

***The form itself has to be an observable***

---

### AppComponent

```html
<div>
  <app-form [asyncData]="asyncData$ | async"></app-form>
</div>
```

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'observableForm';

  asyncData$: ReplaySubject<Data> = new ReplaySubject<Data>(1);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => this.asyncData$.next( {
      id: 42,
      name: 'Han Solo',
      heShotFirst: true
    } as Data), 2000);
  }
}
```

### FormComponent

```html
<div *ngIf="(dataForm$ | async) as dataForm">
    <form [formGroup]="dataForm" style="padding: 5rem; display: grid; place-items: center;">
        <div>
            <label>
                Id
                <input type="text" [formControlName]="'id'">
            </label>
            <label>
                Name
                <input type="text" [formControlName]="'name'">
            </label>
            <br>
            <label>
                He shot first
                <input type="radio" [value]="true" [formControlName]="'heShotFirst'">
            </label>         
            <label>
                He did not
                <input type="radio" [value]="false" [formControlName]="'heShotFirst'">
            </label>         
        </div>
    </form>
    <div *ngIf="(lies$ | async) === false" style="display: grid; place-items: center;">
        <h1>I Must Not Tell Lies</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
export class FormComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() set asyncData(data: Data) { this._asyncData$.next(data); }
  _asyncData$: ReplaySubject<Data> = new ReplaySubject<Data>(1);

  dataForm$: Observable<FormGroup>;
  valueChangesSub$: Subscription;

  lies$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataForm$ = this._asyncData$.pipe(
      map(data => {
        return this.fb.group({
          id: [data?.id],
          name: [data?.name],
          heShotFirst: [data?.heShotFirst]
        });
      }),
      tap(form => {
            if (this.valueChangesSub$ != null) {
              this.valueChangesSub$.unsubscribe();
            }
            return form.valueChanges.subscribe(changes => {
              console.log(changes)
              this.lies$.next(changes.heShotFirst);
            });
          })
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.valueChangesSub$.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to build a small working example with Stackblitz to illustrate how it is not working?

Comment: And I'm curious why the form itself needs to be an observable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't certain why the form needed to be an Observable. I instead used `OnChanges` to watch for changes from the parent component and `valueChanges` to watch for changes to the form.

This is the resulting code:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from "@angular/core";
import { ReplaySubject, Observable, Subscription, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { Data } from "./data";
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";
import { map, tap } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: "app-form",
  templateUrl: "./form.component.html"
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges {
  @Input() asyncData: Data;

  dataForm$: Observable<FormGroup>;
  dataForm: FormGroup;
  valueChangesSub: Subscription;

  lies$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataForm = this.fb.group({
      id: "",
      name: "",
      heShotFirst: false
    });

    this.valueChangesSub = this.dataForm.valueChanges.subscribe(changes => {
      console.log(changes);
      this.lies$.next(changes.heShotFirst);
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    let currentValue: Data = changes.asyncData.currentValue;
    console.log("changes", currentValue);

    if (currentValue !== null) {
      this.dataForm.patchValue({
        id: currentValue.id,
        name: currentValue.name,
        heShotFirst: currentValue.heShotFirst
      });
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.valueChangesSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

I have a stackblitz of this here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-async-form-deborahk

Using the `OnChanges`, the child component gets notified each time a new value is emitted into the parent's stream. (I attempted to mock this by setting a second `setTimeout` in the parent component.)

Then the `valueChanges` on the form seems to work as expected.

If this isn't quite what you were looking for, feel free to fork the stackblitz and modify it as needed to demo your issue.

Comment: The form doesn't HAVE to be an observable per se, it was just to encourage solutions similar to my own. 
But this is a perfectly good alternative to observables, and it looks much cleaner!

Comment: Is it enough to answer your question? If so, please mark it as your answer to close the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about setting up two Observables?

```js
this.dataForm$ = this._asyncData$.pipe(
  map(data => this.fb.group({
    id: [data?.id],
    name: [data?.name],
    heShotFirst: [data?.heShotFirst]
  })),
);
this.lies$ = this.dataForm$.pipe(
  switchMap(form => form.valueChanges),
  map(changes => changes.heShotFirst),
);
```

Comment: That was my initial approach, but for somereason valueChanges does not like to be switchMapped. Or merge- or concatmapped for that matter